# AWS SSM Parameter Store: How can I edit multi-line "SecureString" values using the console?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

Currently, I use a single [SSM parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html) to store a set of properties separated by newlines, like this:

```
property1=value1
property2=value2
property3=value3
```

(I am aware of the 4K size limit, it's fine.)

This works well, for normal `String` type parameters that store non-sensitive information like environment configuration, but I'd also like to do similar for secrets using the `SecureString` parameter type.

The problem is that I can't edit the parameter value in the console because it's using a HTML input field of `type="password"` that doesn't handle newlines.

The multi-line value works fine with the actual parameter store backend - I can set a value with multiple lines with the SSM API no problem and they can be read with the EC2 CLI properly too.

But I can't edit them using the console.  This is a problem because the whole point of using a `SecureString` parameter is that I intend the only place to edit/view these secrets to be via the console (so that permissions are controlled and access is audited).

There's a few infrastructure workarounds I could implement (one parameter for each secret, store the secrets on S3 or other secret storing service, etc.) but they all have drawbacks - I'm just trying to find out if there's a way around this using the console?

Is there any way I can work around this and use the console to edit multi-line SecureString parameters?
Any kind of browser workaround or hack that I might be able to use to tell the browser to use a textarea instead of a "password" type field?
I'm using Chrome, but I'd be happy to work around this by using another browser or something (editing the secrets is pretty rare, and viewing multi-line values in the console works fine).

**EDIT**

After posting this question, AWS notified me there was a whole new "AWS Systems Manager" UI, but it still has the same problem - I tried the below browser hacks on this new UI, but no luck.

Failed browser hack attempt 1: I tried opening the browser console, running `document.getElementById("Value").value = "value1\nvalue2"` and then clicking the save button, which set the value I injected, but the newline was filtered out.

Failed browser hack attempt 2: I tried using the browser inspector to change the element to a `TextArea` and then typed in two lines of input and clicked save, but that didn't set the value at all.

Comment: Something we do at work is input something like `property1=value1\nproperty2=value2\nproperty3=value3`, and after reading the value from ssm substitute the `\n` for an actual linebreak. I would be interested if there is a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided the answer to this question is "don't do that". Not that I would've wanted to hear that when I was trying to make it work.

You should use a separate SSM param per secret for these reasons:

- ability to grant permissions at fine grained level; e.g. you have an API password for calling your service, and a DB password for the service talk to a DB - if you store them in the same secret you couldn't only grant access to the API password.
- ability to track key access separately - the SSM access logs can only tell you that the target machine/user accessed the SSM param at that time, it won't be able to tell you which secret was accessed
- ability to use separate KMS keys to encrypt

Just watch out for the fact that you can only request a max of 10 SSM params at a time.

Answer (score 12):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-using-param.html#cli-using-param-file, I learned you can pass a file as parameter to the `--value` argument. So if your file is called `secrets.properties`, you can do this:

```
aws ssm put-parameter --type SecureString --name secrets --value file://secrets.properties
```

Comment: Yeah, but I was using the console.

Comment: didnt know about the file option and had a hard time without it. made my day!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it, but it's too much effort and too weird - if anyone can find a simpler way, I will mark that as the answer.

The hacky workaround is to install the "Tamper Chrome" extension + app, then capture the XHR request as the browser sends it and edit the new lines into the JSON.

Blech. Plus "Tamper Chrome" is pretty awful, I don't want to run it on my machine.

Comment: Using aws-cli or another mechanism for direct API requests seem to be the only solutions.  It appears to be an unfortunate design flaw in the console.

Comment: I can't even get this to work via the aws cli. Adding newline characters just results in them being interpreted literally (escaped). Did you know of a way to make it work?

Comment: @darrend I'm actually using Terraform, so it's the thing that's putting the newlines into the value via the API, not me.  But I am getting the values out using the aws cli, so reading definitely works.  But I don't actually have proof that you can write newlines to a param value using the command line (but I'd guess that it should work and you should probably look at your quoting/escaping mechanism).

Comment: @Shorn thanks, I figured it out in the end but you need to use the `--cli-input-json` switch and pass the value as a json object (edit: I'll add as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

This might be better to use the new [secrets manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-secrets-manager-store-distribute-and-rotate-credentials-securely/) that was launched recently. The interface for it is very close to parameter store but it has better support for multiple parameters in one place.

I wonder if the change in the console was due to the expected release of the service since they have a pricing model around secrets whereas parameter store is free

Comment: I don't understand the point of secrets manager, it seems expensive for what it does.  I've just gone with separating the secrets with a tab character, then converting that to newline with "sed -e 'y/\t/\n/'" on the instance.  I really shouldn't have to do that - especially given the secrets manager doesn't seem to "need" a password type field, why shouldn't I be able to use a textarea for the parameter store.  Whatevs, it's done now.

Answer (score 0):

if you want, you can try with my app https://github.com/ledongthuc/awssecretsmanagerui

I try to create it to easier to update multi-line values and binary easier. Hope it's helpful with your case.